# How much money I can take with me to the Philippines?

Tags: money, philippines, moroccan-citizens

I will travel to the Philippines for a vacation. How much money am I allowed to bring with me in cash?

I'm a citizen of Morocco.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Phillipine Consulate in Australia](http://www.philippineconsulate.com.au/bringing-currency-into-the-philippines.html):

> No permit is required from the Bangko Sentral ng Pilipinas to bring in to or to take out from the Philippines of foreign currencies.  However, foreign currency in excess of US$10,000 carried by the traveler must be declared at the Bureau of Customs Desk in the airport.

Therefore the answer to your question is: you can import as much cash as you want (in foreign currencies), but amounts over 10000`USD` must be declared.

"Forreign currencies" include all currencies except the Phillippine peso.

Comment: Hello, By foreign currencies you mean dollars for example?
My home currencies is in MAD ( Moroccan dirhams ), Do I need to exchange that to USD or Euro first? or to Philippine pesos?

Comment: @reda yes, all currencies worldwide except the peso.

Comment: @reda since Moroccan dirhams are not widely accepted outside Morocco you should change them to USD or EUR first.